# Vue composition api is not updating bound value to text field

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am updating an attribute of an object after initialization.

My dumbed-down component looks like this:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    v-text-field(v-model="object.name")
    v-text-field(v-model="object.vpnPort")
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'
export default {
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const object = ref({})

    getNextPort().then(response => (object.value.vpnPort = response.data))

    return { object }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this example, `getNextPort` is an API call that returns a number. For some reason, the `v-text-field` is not updated. I do not see the value in the input field. When I `console.log` the object after the `getNextPort` call it shows:

```
{"vpnPort":10001}
```

Which is the expected result. I also tried:

- `$nextTick`
- `onMounted`
- `$forceUpdate`

But when I start typing in the name field the vpnPort doest get updated!

Does anybody know why the result is not shown in the v-text-field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your `object` data with empty fields like :

```
const object = ref({
  name:'',
  vpnPort:null
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

for reactive objects, you should use `reactive`

```
const object = reactive({
  name: '',
  vpnPort: null
})
```

change

```
object.value.vpnPort = response.data
```

to

```
object.vpnPort = response.data
```

check out https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#ref-vs-reactive for more info